# How to merge the contents of two variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have many string variables that start with "Question" and then end with a number. ("Question1")
Each variable has a question in it ("How many times does it say E?")
There is an editable textbox on the stage that the user types in which question number he want to be displayed in a different textbox. ("1")
When the user clicks a button, I want that the text of *Question1* should be displayed in the textbox.
 My code looks like this:

```
var Question1:String = "How many times does it say E?" ;
var Question2:String = "How many times does it say B?" ;
var Question3:String = "How many times does it say A?" ;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayQuestion);

function displayQuestion(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var QuestionNumber:Number = Number(userInputQuestionNumber.text);

    textBoxDisplayQuestion.text= Question(QuestionNumber);
}
```

How can I get the *textBoxDisplayQuestion* to display the actual text of the Question??
(the code i have now obviously is not working!!)

But this example doesnt seem to work: I created a class called *Question* and here is the code:

```
import Question;
var QuNoLoad:Number;
var Qu1:Question = new Question(1,"how","yes","no","maybe","so","AnsB","AnsA");

trace(Qu1.QuNo, Qu1.Qu, Qu1.AnsA,Qu1.AnsB, Qu1.AnsC, Qu1.AnsD, Qu1.CorAns, Qu1.FaCorAns);

//the following is the code for the button
loadQu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadQuClick);

function loadQuClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //this sets the variable "QuNoLoad" with the contents of the "textBoxQuLoad"
    //imagine the user inputed "1"
    QuNoLoad=Number(textBoxQuLoad.text);

    //this SHOULD!! display the contents of "Qu1.Qu"
    textQu.text= this["Qu"+QuNoLoad.toString()+".Qu"]
    //and when i traced this statment the value was "undefined"
}
```

Why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty fundamental concept in programming that will make a lot of things harder to do until you understand it well, and it's pretty hard to explain without starting with some groundwork:

What's happening here is easiest to talk about with plain old `Object` rather than classes, so lets start with a very simple example:

```
var question1:Object = new Object();
question1.number = 1;
```

Note that with `Object` you didn't have to say that `number` existed ahead of time, it gets created when you set it. Now, when you say either `question1.number` you get 1, obviously. What is happening, however is that first `question1` gets the *value* you stored in the *variable* `question1` (which is `{ number: 1 }`), then the `.number` gets the value stored in the *property* `number` stored in that value: `1`.

To save some typing, you can use a shorthand called "object literals":

```
var question1 = {
   number: 1
};
```

Now lets try a more complex object:

```
var question1 = {
   number: 1,
   text: "How many times does it say A?",
   answers: {
       a: 1,
       b: 2,
       c: 3,
       d: 4,
       correct: "b"
   }
};
```

Now `question1` is an object that has 3 properties, one of which, `answers`, is an object with 5 properties: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `correct`. This could also be written as:

```
var question1 = new Object();
question1.number = 1;
question1.text = "How many times does it say A?";
question1.answers = new Object();
question1.answers.a = 1;
question1.answers.b = 2;
question1.answers.c = 3;
question1.answers.d = 4;
question1.answers.correct = "b";
```

It should be pretty clear why the literal syntax exists now!

This time, if you say `question1.answers.correct` you get `"b"`: first `question1` gets you the `{ number: 1,`...`}` value, then the `.answers` gets the `{ a: 1, b: 2,`...`}` value, then finally the `.correct` gets the `"b"` value.

You should also know that `this` is a special variable that has a particular meaning in ActionScript (and JavaScript, on which it is based): it *broadly* refers to the object in when the code you are writing is inside: for "global" code (not inside a `function`), `var` adds properties to this object: `var number = 2;` and `this.number = 2` are this same here. (This is **not** true when you're in `function`, `this` behaves differently there, sometimes in very strange ways, so be careful!)

Now you might start seeing what's happening: when you use `[]`, for example, `question1["number"]`, rather than `question1.number`, you are passing the property name you want to get as a `String` **value**, which means you can change what property you get while you are running, rather than when you compile ("runtime" vs. "compiletime"), but it *also* lets you get properties with names you can't refer to with the `.` syntax!

```
var strange = {
    "a strange name? That's OK!": 1
};
trace(strange["a strange name? That's OK!"]);
```

So when you write `this["Qu" + QuNoLoad.toString() + ".QuNo"]`, you create a name like `"Qu2.QuNo"`, for example, you are trying to get a property with that exact name, `.` included, which doesn't exist! What you were trying to do the equivalent of: `Qu2.QuNo` could be written as `this["Qu" + QuNoLoad].QuNo`.

I shouldn't leave this without saying, though, that for something like this, I would use arrays, which exist so that you can use a single name to store a list of values:

```
var questions:Array = [ // set questions to an array with multiple questions
    new Question(...),
    new Question(...),
    ...
];

for each (var question:Question in questions) { // Look at each question in the array
    if (question.QuNo == textBoxQuLoad.text) { // If this is the right question
        loadQuestion(question);
        break; // Found it, stop looking at each question by "breaking out" of the for each
    }
}
```

There's lots more you can do with arrays, so read up on them when you get time.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference a variable by name using square brackets `[]` operator, such as:

```
this["Question" + QuestionNumber.toString()]
```

You may use this operator to dynamically set and retrieve values for a property of an object.

Keeping the question number as an integer, your function would be:

```
var Question1:String = "How many times does it say E?" ;
var Question2:String = "How many times does it say B?" ;
var Question3:String = "How many times does it say A?" ;

function displayQuestion(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var QuestionNumber:uint = uint(userInputQuestionNumber.text);

    textBoxDisplayQuestion.text = this["Question" + QuestionNumber.toString()];
}
```

Comment: You can't have a period `.` in a variable name.  If it's a member, then you want: `this["Qu"+QuNoLoad.toString()].Qu`  Ask a new question instead of expanding your existing question.